# How to insert different size of same product in cart or database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a basic e-commerce site with PHP and MySQL. When I click on `add to cart` in product page it will add to cart but if I click on same product but different size it will not insert into cart. Can someone help me solve my issue? I'm beginner in PHP and MySQL.

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_cart'])) {
  $the_product_id = $_GET['p_id'];
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE cart_user_id='{$user_id}' AND cart_product_id=' {$the_product_id}'  ";
  $select_from_product = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_from_product)) {


    $cart_product_id = $row['cart_product_id'];
    $cart_product_size = $row['cart_product_size'];


  }

  if ($cart_product_id == null || $cart_product_id == ' ' && $cart_product_size == null) {
    $addquery = "INSERT INTO carts(cart_user_id, cart_product_id, cart_product_quantity, cart_product_size) VALUES('{$user_id}','{$the_product_id}','{$quantity}','{$size}')";
    redirect("cart.php");
    $add_to_cart = mysqli_query($connection, $addquery);

    $p_query = "UPDATE product SET product_quantity= product_quantity-$quantity WHERE product_quantity > 0 and product_id = '{$the_product_id}'";
    $up_query = mysqli_query($connection, $p_query);
  } else {
    echo "This product already to your cart";
  }
```

Comment: Give your `carts` table structure, with the details of any constraints on it.

Comment: You dont check if the size exists already I think that is the problem.

Comment: On a different note, are you creating this ecommerce website just for your learning purpose ? Or, as an actual work project ? If it is an actual project, my sincere recommendation would be to not reinvent wheel by yourself. Better take a look at some opensource ecommerce projects such as [Opencart](https://github.com/opencart/opencart)

Comment: for learning purpose

Comment: can u help madhur Bhaiya

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the product existence in cart using product id and user id. 
`$query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE cart_user_id='{$user_id}' AND cart_product_id=' {$the_product_id}'  ";`

So if you select a product first time then it is added. Second time when you try to add the product in cart, there is already a product with same product id, but with different size in cart. so following condition is never fulfilled. 
`if($cart_product_id == null || $cart_product_id == ' ' &&  $cart_product_size == null ){`

You need to include size in where clause of first query i.e 
`$query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE cart_user_id='{$user_id}' AND cart_product_id=' {$the_product_id}'  ";`

Also redirect should be after queries. But that is another issue.
There are other issues in code too. So this answer is related to your specific question.

Comment: what can i do for that?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE cart_user_id='{$user_id}' AND cart_product_id=' {$the_product_id}'  AND cart_product_size <> '{$size}' "

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE cart_user_id='{$user_id}' AND cart_product_id=' {$the_product_id}' AND cart_product_size = $size ";
```

Comment: i tried it works but when i click again the same product and  same size added again into another row in cart.

Comment: i tried but it add again and same product and size in different row

Comment: What can i do abhay

Comment: before inserting check that ,Is there any product with current size exists? if there is no such product then insert into cart table.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM carts WHERE cart_user_id= ' ".$user_id." '  AND cart_product_id= ' ".$the_product_id." ' AND cart_product_size =  ' ".$size ." ' " ;